# Not able to match a regexp - Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I have this code in Jquery -:

```
message = '#Usain Bolt #Usain Bolt #Usain Bolt'; message = " "+message+" ";
var type1 = 'Usain Bolt';                                                       
if(message.match(type1))
{ 
  var matchOne = new RegExp(' #'+type1+' ', 'g');  
  var matchTwo = new RegExp('\n#'+type1+' ', 'g'); 

  message = message.replace(matchOne," @"+type1+" ").replace(matchTwo,"\n@"+type1+" ");  
}
```

The resulting message should be `@Usain Bolt @Usain Bolt @Usain Bolt`
 
But it becomes -: `@Usain Bolt #Usain Bolt @Usain Bolt`

Whats the problem. Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the spaces between `#Usain Bolt`s are part of the match.

```
" #Usain Bolt #Usain Bolt #Usain Bolt "
 ^-----------^                         first match
                         ^-----------^ second match
             ^-----------^             no match (a character can only match once)
```

Use word boundaries instead:

```
message = '#Usain Bolt #Usain Bolt #Usain Bolt';
var type1 = 'Usain Bolt';                                                       
if(message.match(type1))
{ 
  var matchOne = new RegExp('#\\b'+type1+'\\b', 'g');  
  var matchTwo = new RegExp('\n#\\b'+type1+'\\b', 'g'); 

  message = message.replace(matchOne," @"+type1).replace(matchTwo,"\n@"+type1);  
}
```

Comment: @RayZ: They match at the position between word characters (which include letters, digits and the underscore: `\w`) and non-word characters (or the start/end of the string).